# automate a bash script which asks for password

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script bash script which generate/creates openssl certs and copies it to servers/devices.
Each time it try to SCP the host it asks for password.

I want to write a python code which calls this script and automatically enter the password when it prompts without user intervention.

How to achieve this? Share you valuable suggestion please.

Comment: `expect` is a specialized tool for automated interaction with scripts, but it's not Python.

Comment: maybe you could add SSH keys to accces without login. [3 Steps to Perform SSH Login Without Password Using ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/). And then `scp` should also access without login.

Comment: did you try to do it with `subprocess` in python?

Comment: as @VPfB mentioned you can try `expect` - there is also version in Python [Pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)